Optimizing over convex polynomials
I have a minimization problem which reads $\min\limits_P J(P)$, where the minimum is over convex polynomials in $n$ variables, with degree at most $d$, and $J$ is a function taking polynomials as input, and returning a scalar.
For instance, $J(P)$ can be based on the coefficient of $P$, on the values taken by $P$ or its derivatives at some given point, etc.
I actually want to solve this problem numerically. The problem is to enforce convexity of $P$. I've looked into sos-polynomials and related notions, but I am still a bit lost.
At some point, I was thinking of defining some polynomial matrix $S$, and setting $\nabla^2 P(x) = S(x)^T S(x)$, but given $S$, nothing guarantees that $S^T S$ is indeed a valid hessian matrix. If I want to optimize directly over $P$, then enforcing its convexity does not seem easy...
Any ideas ? Thank you !
